# I need help swapping this string

Tags: c++, string, loops, swap

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sentence;
    string output;
    string product1;
    string product2;
    char pr1;
    string product;
    
    int i;
    getline (cin,sentence);
    char pr2;
    
    cin >> pr1;
    cin >> pr2;
    
    for (i=0; i < sentence.length();i++){
        
        pr1 = sentence[i]; //asdfg---> g
        pr2 = sentence[0]; //--> a 
    }
    
    output += pr1+sentence+pr2;

    cout << output;
    return 0;
}
```

This code is made to swap letters, but for example when I enter `asdfg` I get `gaasdfga`. When I enter that, I want to swap `g` and `a`. Any idea what I should do? Any idea what's wrong, and how I can improve it?

Comment: Replace all the modifications to `sentence` except reading the string from stdin with `std::reverse(sentence.begin(), sentence.end());` and simply print `sentence` instead of something else?

Comment: You should really explain what you want to do. If the standard input is `nbvcx⏎qw` what do you expect to obtain? And if it's `aaaaabbbbb⏎ab`?

Comment: If I somehow misunderstood the question, please clarify by adding some example input and the expected output to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The below assigns new values to `pr1` and `pr2`. The characters you entered will be lost.

```
    pr1 = sentence[i]; //asdfg---> g
    pr2 = sentence[0]; //--> a
```

To swap the first found of each of the two entered characters, use [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and then [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap)

Example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string sentence = "asdfg";

    char pr1 = 'g';
    char pr2 = 'a';

    auto pos1 = sentence.find(pr1);
    auto pos2 = sentence.find(pr2);

    if(pos1 != sentence.npos && pos2 != sentence.npos) {
        std::swap(sentence[pos1], sentence[pos2]);
    }

    std::cout << sentence << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
gsdfa
```

An alternative to `std::swap(sentence[pos1], sentence[pos2]);` would be to do the swap manually:

```
char temp = sentence[pos1];
sentence[pos1] = sentence[pos2];
sentence[pos2] = temp;
```

or via a user defined `swapper` function that you call just like you'd call `std::swap`:

```
template<class T>
void swapper(T& lhs, T& rhs) {
    // move construct a temporary variable from the argument on the
    // left hand side
    T temp = std::move(lhs);

    // move assign the left hand side from the right hand side
    lhs = std::move(rhs);

    // move assign the right hand side from the temporary variable
    rhs = std::move(temp);
}
```

Comment: Any idea how I can do it manually because that's what they want me to do in university

Comment: @Jasmine Sure. Are you familiar with templates or would you prefer a non-template solution? Perhaps you could update the question to provide more details and we can reopen it.

Comment: What I would prefer is a solution that is simple for me to understand please majority of things i find on the intrenet either use functions or are too complicated so mind telling me where i can find something simple?

Comment: @Jasmine I see. Does the alternative I just added help?

Comment: Like a template solution that is easy to undertand would be very helpful thanks

Comment: @Jasmine Ok, I added a `swapper` function template with some explanations.

Comment: @Jasmine Perhaps it would be best if you wrote a new question where you clearly explain the exact thing you do need help with. I'll vote to delete this question since it can't be answered with the information we have at hand.